# ASP.NET routing - avoiding clashes between controller/action and vanity/slug urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking for a good solution to having a URL scheme that works for both standard ASP.NET MVC controller/action urls eg:

```
/Home/About --> Controller "Home", Action "About"
```

and vanity/slug urls eg:

```
/fred/post  --> Controller "Posts", Action "View", User "fred", Post "post"
```

Importantly, I want the outbound url generation to work so that

```
Html.ActionLink("View", "Posts", new { User="fred", Post="post" }, null }
```

gives /fred/post - not /Posts/View/fred/post

It seems, I can get it to work for either inbound or outbound routing but not both.  Or I can get it sort of working but it's messy and prone to breaking.  What approaches, tips and tricks are there to getting something like this working cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution of using a routing constraint that can check if a parameter matches (or doesn't match) the name of a controller:

```
public class ControllerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    static List<string> ControllerNames = (from t in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                           where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.Name.EndsWith("Controller")
                                           select t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.Length - 10).ToLower()).ToList();

    bool m_bIsController;
    public ControllerConstraint(bool IsController)
    {

        m_bIsController = IsController;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (m_bIsController)
            return ControllerNames.Contains(values[parameterName].ToString().ToLower());
        else
            return !ControllerNames.Contains(values[parameterName].ToString().ToLower());
    }  
}
```

Use like this:

```
// eg: /myusername
routes.MapRoute(
    "MemberUrl",
    "{member_urlid}",
    new { controller = "Members", action = "View" },
    new { action="View", member_urlid = new ControllerConstraint(false) }
);

// eg: /myusername/mypagename
routes.MapRoute(
    "ItemUrl",
    "{member_urlid}/{item_urlid}",
    new { controller = "Items", action = "View" },
    new { action="View", member_urlid = new ControllerConstraint(false) }
);

// Normal controller/action routes follow
```

The constraint `new ControllerConstraint(false)` means don't match this routing rule if the parameter matches the name of a controller.  Pass true to make the constraint check that the parameter does match a controller name.

Comment: OK--but what if a user signs up with the username "About" and then you eventually decide you need an AboutController after they sign up. How is the resolution taking place? `/about/` maps to what? The user? Your new controller? I am wondering how to handle these root vanity URLs but for future proofiness I am considering simply using `/users/{username}` instead. Ideas? You can have a list of reserved words but there *will* be something later that you never thought of... right?